# How to use one class's method in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm creating a poker game and I have a Card deck class which has methods getDeck, getCard and getCards(howMany) and a Card component. I need to use CardDeck's method in App, because I need to save the deck in state to splice already used cards and generate new deck after 52 cards are used. 
I've got a button that generates new 5 cards (a hand) and I need another one to generate new deck.

this is my app.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      display: false,
      cards: CardDeck.getCards(5)
    }
  }
  displayDeck = () => {
    this.setState({display: true});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className='btn' onClick={this.displayDeck}>Button</button>
        {this.state.display ?
           <div className="App playingCards fourColours faceImages">
           <Card rank={this.state.cards[0].rank} suit={this.state.cards[0].suit} />
           <Card rank={this.state.cards[1].rank} suit={this.state.cards[1].suit} />
           <Card rank={this.state.cards[2].rank} suit={this.state.cards[2].suit} />
           <Card rank={this.state.cards[3].rank} suit={this.state.cards[3].suit} />
           <Card rank={this.state.cards[4].rank} suit={this.state.cards[4].suit} />
         </div> :
           null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
  }
```

this is my CardDeck class:

```
let getRandomInt = (min, max) => {    
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
class CardDeck {
    constructor () {
        this.deck = this.getDeck();
    }
    getDeck = () => {
        const suits = ['hearts', 'diams', 'clubs', 'spades'];
        const ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'j', 'q', 'k', 'a'];
        let currentDeck = [];
        for (let suit of suits) {
            for (let rank of ranks) {
                let card = {suit: suit, rank: rank};
                currentDeck.push(card);
            }
        }
        return currentDeck;
    }
    getCard = () => {
        let min = 0;
        let max = 52;
        let card;
        while (card === undefined) {
            let number = getRandomInt(min, max);
            card = this.deck[number];
            this.deck.splice(number, 1);
        }
        return card;
    }
    getCards = howMany => {
        let cardsArray = [];
        for (let i=0; i < howMany; i++) {
            let card = this.getCard();
            cardsArray.push(card);
        }
        return cardsArray;
    }

}
```

my Card component:

```
class Card extends Component {
    render(props) {
        const suits = {
            diams: '♦',
            hearts: '♥',
            clubs: '♣',
            spades: '♠'
        };
        const ranks = {
            'q': 'Q',
            'j': 'J',
            'k': 'K',
            'a': 'A',
            '2': '2',
            '3': '3',
            '4': '4',
            '5': '5',
            '6': '6',
            '7': '7',
            '8': '8',
            '9': '9',
            '10': '10'
        }
        var  classNames = "card " +  "rank-" + this.props.rank + " " + this.props.suit;
        return (
            <div className={classNames}>
                <span className="rank">{ranks[this.props.rank]}</span>
                <span className="suit">{suits[this.props.suit]}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you are trying to call CardDeck.getCards, is thats the issue ?

Comment: yes, exactly, and the error says 'default.getCards is not a function'

Comment: i have posted the answer please let me know whether it worked for you

Comment: If you don't want to instantiate a `new CardDeck()` then make your `getCards` method `static` like I wrote in my answer, try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using a class , you need to take instance of the class.

so replace with the below snippet. I hope this will solve the issue

```
//App.js
    constructor() {
        super();
        let carDeck = new CardDeck()
        this.state = {
          display: false,
          cards: carDeck.getCards(5)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Happy to hear but didn't accepted the answer. I thought snippet will help you. If else will update the theory part also ☺️☺️

Answer (score 1):

The issue I see here is you are not making an instance of the class you are trying to access the method for. `CardDeck` is another class, to use it's method usually you need to make a new instance of `CardDeck` like DILEEP THOMAS has written in his answer.

If you don't want to instantiate a `new CardDeck()` then make your `getCards` method `static` like so: `static getCards = howMany => { // code }`. 
This way you can access this method outside of it's class without creating a new instance of that class.